# How to prevent open link when user dragging and ends dragging element?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, carousel, pure-react-carousel

I using ***react-responsive-carousel*** for carousel and I need to prevent open link when user dragging and ends dragging the element
Help me 
How can I do this?
small example what I mean:
[image]

Comment: please don't use screenshots of your code. use an actual code instead.